# How to do multiple JOINS at once in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord

I got these two tables where one table is having multiple foreign keys to the second table.

Table `rankings`

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| search_text    | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| first_item_id  | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| second_item_id | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| third_item_id  | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| forth_item_id  | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table `items`

```
+---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                        | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| item_code                 | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+---------------------------+
```

Sample data `rankings`

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
| id | search_text | first | second | third | forth |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
|  1 | test 1      |     1 |      2 |     3 |     4 |
|  2 | test 2      |     1 |      2 |     3 |     4 |
|  3 | test 3      |     1 |      2 |     3 |     4 |
|  4 | test 4      |     1 |      2 |     3 |     4 |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
```

Sample data `items`

```
+--------+------------+
| id     | item_code  |
+--------+------------+
|      1 | 125659     |
|      2 | 125660     |
|      3 | 125661     |
|      4 | 125662     |
+--------+------------+
```

At the moment im retrieving the ranking data as follows :

```
@rankings = Admin::Ranking.all
```

Expected data

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
| id | search_text | first | second | third | forth |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
|  1 | test 1      | 125659| 125660 | 125661| 125662|
|  2 | test 2      | 125659| 125660 | 125661| 125662|
|  3 | test 3      | 125659| 125660 | 125661| 125662|
|  4 | test 4      | 125659| 125660 | 125661| 125662|
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
```

The SQL query to retrieve the expected data :

```
SELECT 
  r.id,
  r.search_text,
  i1.item_code AS first,
  i2.item_code AS second,
  i3.item_code AS third,
  i4.item_code AS forth
FROM rankings r
LEFT JOIN items i1 ON i1.id = r.first_item_id
LEFT JOIN items i2 ON i2.id = r.second_item_id
LEFT JOIN items i3 ON i3.id = r.third_item_id
LEFT JOIN items i4 ON i4.id = r.forth_item_id
ORDER BY r.id;
```

Model classes are as follow:

`items` -> `Item`,
`rankings` -> `Ranking`

Any suggestion on how to retrieve ranking data in expected format using Rails `ActiveRecord`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate association for each foreign key.

```
class Ranking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :first_item, class_name: 'Item'
  belongs_to :second_item, class_name: 'Item'
  belongs_to :third_item, class_name: 'Item'
  belongs_to :forth_item, class_name: 'Item'
end
```

Then you can just include all of them and query as needed.

```
rankings = Ranking.all.includes(:first_item, :second_item, :third_item, :forth_item)
rankings.each do |ranking|
  ranking.first_item.item_code # example
end
```

This is the ActiveRecord way. If you want to get exactly only the `item_code`-s and nothing else, you could `.select` it instead.

Comment: Yes that worked thanks. Can you mention how to use the `.select` as well if i want to include only the `item_code`s inside the `@rankings`